# How to see package history?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I see the history of a package in the Npm registry?

In particular, I want to know when https://npmjs.org/package/npm version 1.1.2 was released.

Comment: Also, is there any way to check on the web?

Comment: I have tried to answer it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092343/2102114

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You could do `npm view npm` there are some options you can find at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

e.g. `npm view npm@1.1.2 time`

Comment: I replaced it with the new link

Comment: `npm view <package>@<version> time` prints `undefined`.  (using npm v3.10.8)

Comment: This seems to be a bug, i reported it at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15573 we will see what the outcome is

Comment: Any chance to add the commits to the output as well?

Comment: Is it possible to see the history of installed versions?

Comment: how would you get just the 'created' and 'modified' as I need the just package initial publishing date and the last modified dates.

Comment: What timezone is the time in?

Answer (score 7):

For those wondering how to view these details online. There is a slightly ugly* way I found to do that. Here's how

1. Assuming your package name is `<packageName>` go to `https://registry.npmjs.org/<packageName>` the JSON here is probably the same thing you get when you run `npm view`
2. Do a Ctrl+F(or equivalent) to search for `"time":{` or `"<your_version_number>"`
3. You can find the version release date under the "time" key.

For example if you want to find out when version 1.1.25 (couldn't find 1.1.2) of npm was released. You can go to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm 
Search for "1.1.25" and iterate till you find a value under the "time" key or search for `"time":{` (whichever is easier) and there you have it!

> "time":{"modified":"2017-10-13T18:58:10.523Z","created":"2013-07-12T18:32:48.902Z",**"1.1.25":"2013-07-12T18:32:49.875Z"**...

*Ugly because you have to parse the JSON to understand the mess :)

Comment: Any way to do it with @types/xyz?

Comment: @MarkSowul unfortunately I wasnt able to find a way to do that. Running `npm view @types/node` for example returns a tarball URL `https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node/-/node-9.4.6.tgz` at the end but navigating to `https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/node` gives `{}`. Maybe npm registry has blocked packages containing the `@` symbol from being queried?

Answer (score 2):

For some specific versions I have found that time is not present and therefore the package is not listed when running that command. To see a list of all available times for a package run this command: `npm view <package> time`. To see all versions and history run `npm view <package> versions`.